# restoring permission i have accidently given using chmod

Tags: 16.04, chmod

Accidently while changing the writing, reading rights for the folder, i gave all the rights for editing my HOME directory, using

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home
```

I came to know about it, after seeing different color combo of highlighted directories, ( i.e. all the constituent directories are coming in green background with blue font ) 
now can anyone help me backing up original rights, or to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you the only user? Are there other users in the `/home` directory? Such as `/home/user`, `/home/user2`?

Comment: @user68186 currently i am the only user,

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to revert it as far as I know, but to fix your problem, you can use this command to give directories 755 and folders 644 chmod:

```
sudo find /home/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /home/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: i will see to it, but in addition to this, what problems i will be facing, as currently, i am the only user,

Comment: Running this command as the only user won't cause any problems. You might get errors with some applications, for example, SSH keys require chmod 600, and won't be usable without this chmod.